# Can we let the [Bloomberg] tag blossom?

Tags: discussion, tags

Whilst strolling around SO I came across the [bloomberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bloomberg) tag. It's not a big tag, with around 400 questions present, but it caught my attention. Is this a tag that we would want to keep around I wonder?

The excerpt has little to do with anything vaguely related to programming:

> Bloomberg L.P. is a financial news and data service. They provide extensive support for their own products.

And the tag wiki doesn't help much either:

> Bloomberg L.P. is a financial news and data service that provides an API for real time access to financial information.
>
> Bloomberg L.P. provides a computer system that enables financial professionals to access the Bloomberg Professional service, known as Bloomberg Terminal.
>
> Bloomberg provides extensive, expensive, and responsive support. They can field any question about their service. Please consider whether your question would be better directed to them.

It almost looks like an advertisement on how awesome their customer-service is.

I made a quick look at the burnination questionaire, but am not sure if we should keep it or get rid of it?

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

Well there aren't a great deal of bloombergs around in this world, so it would be unambiguous. It doesn't really describe the content of the questions, as it is rather broad. Usually there is a vague link to some of their API's.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I wouldn't really call it a concept, more a company. And questions relating to their API might be on-topic, but most questions in the tag are VLQ. (Which is an entirely different problem ofcourse)

3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

Usually not.

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Most likely.

So what are you're thoughts on this tag? Should we clear up the tag from any garbage, and remove the tag where it is only vaguely related to the question at hand. Or can we just burninate the hell out of it?

Comment: My first thought on reading the title of this question was..."I bet they have an API that is commonly used by programmers." And yes, that turns out to be exactly correct. So, no. The tag is not bad; it doesn't need to be burninated or any such thing. The tag wikis just need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: I suggested an edit to the [tag:bloomberg] tag description and excerpt.